# Typescript get contextual typing for method parameters

Tags: typescript, inheritance, parameters, decorator, type-inference

---

UPDATE: I found a decently ergonomic way to do this, by explicitly restating the type in the subclass:

```js
type GameActions = {[key: string]: (game: GameState) => any}

class Ship extends GameObject {
   actions : GameActions = {
      onClick(game)  {
        game.explodeShip(); // <-- game is contextually inferred to be of type GameState
      }
   }
}
```

Leaving the rest of the original question here for context:

---

First, let me indicate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
class GameObject {
  actions: {[key: string]: (game: GameState) => any}

  constructor() {
     // It's important that I do some wiring on init time with all actions,
     // but may not be too relevant to the solutions here.
     Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(registerAction);
  }
}

class Ship extends GameObject {
   actions = {
      onClick(game)  {
        game.explodeShip(); // <-- game is contextually inferred to be of type GameState
      }
   }
}
```

Instead, my action methods are all implicitly 'any', and I have to manually type each one, even though it knows it can't be anything else:

```js
onClick(game) {}             // <-- Implicit any, I want implicit GameState
onclick(game: any) {}        // <-- Works and I don't want it to
onClick(game: GameState) {}  // <-- Works but I don't want to have to
onClick(game: NotGame) {}    // <-- Causes TypeError, which is good.
```

So it limits my parameter to supersets of `GameState` - but I want to limit it to **only** `GameState`, since superset includes `any` which is useless.

Typing `GameState` every time is fine - but in practice I have several parameters like this, eg `(game: GameState, dt: number, obj: Ship)`, and I'd rather not write all of those each time, if an object has a dozen actions.

I've tried a few other approaches. Here's one that works, but has too much other boilerplate that it's a wash:

```js
const createAction = (name: string, func: (game: GameState, dt: number) => any) {
   registerAction(name, func);
   return func;
} 

class Ship extends GameObject {
  onClick = createAction('onClick', (game, dt) => {
    game.doSomething() // <-- This works nicely, game is of type GameState
  })
}
```

This works, but I'd rather not have to proxy it through another function to get typing. I also tried with *decorators* but they don't appear to work that way:

```js
type Action = (game: GameState, dt: number) => any
function action<T extends GameObject>(target: T, prop: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Action>) {
   registerAction(target[prop]);
};

class Ship extends GameObject {
  @action
  onClick(game, dt) {
    game.doSomething() // <-- Nope - game is 'any'
  })
}
```

Is there a way I can get the best of both worlds? I want GameObject classes to be as straightforward and readable as possible, with the engine taking care of the complexity. The parameter of an action can only ever be a `GameState` - how can I enforce that more strongly?

Comment: Yeah there’s no contextual typing for subclass methods (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911) and decorators don’t mutate types. There may be workarounds other than your helper function but I doubt any will be able more ergonomic.

Comment: I was able to find a slightly more ergonomic version that works for me, by specifying the type on `actions`:

```actions : GameActions = { onClick(game) }}```